How to create animated gif using the Magick.net library ? it's creating animated gif but small file only from 2-3 files
The first version i tried was creating a fine animated gif taken all 21 images in the List and creating a 13MB size animated gif.
the problem it was not async and cause the application. freezing.
once i changed the code and tried to make it async it's creating a small file of size 1.8MB with only 2-3 frames inside.
this is the async version.  i also added events to report progress.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using ImageMagick;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace Download_Files
{
    public class GifAnimator
    {
        public event EventHandler<int> ProgressChanged;
        public event EventHandler<string> CurrentFileProcessing;
        public event EventHandler<double> ProcessingSpeed;

        public async Task CreateAnimatedGifAsync(string outputFilePath, List<string> imagePaths, int frameDelay)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => // Offload to background thread
            {
                using (var collection = new MagickImageCollection())
                {
                    int totalCount = imagePaths.Count;
                    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                    for (int i = 0; i < totalCount; i++)
                    {
                        string imagePath = imagePaths[i];
                        CurrentFileProcessing?.Invoke(this, imagePath);

                        var image = new MagickImage(imagePath)
                        {
                            AnimationDelay = frameDelay
                        };
                        collection.Add(image);

                        int progressPercentage = (int)((i + 1) / (double)totalCount * 100);
                        ProgressChanged?.Invoke(this, progressPercentage);

                        double speed = (i + 1) / stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
                        ProcessingSpeed?.Invoke(this, speed);
                    }

                    collection.Write(outputFilePath);
                    stopwatch.Stop();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

then using it in form1
private async void AnimatedGifButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var images = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\New folder (76)", "Image*.*");

    List<string> imagePaths = images.ToList();
    GifAnimator animator = new GifAnimator();
    animator.ProgressChanged += Animator_ProgressChanged;
    animator.CurrentFileProcessing += Animator_CurrentFileProcessing;
    animator.ProcessingSpeed += Animator_ProcessingSpeed;

    // Async call to the modified method
    await animator.CreateAnimatedGifAsync(@"d:\output5.gif", imagePaths, 10);
}

private void Animator_ProgressChanged(object sender, int e)
{
    // Update your progress bar
    Invoke(new Action(() => progressBar1.Value = e));
}

private void Animator_CurrentFileProcessing(object sender, string e)
{
    // Update label or text box showing current file being processed
    Invoke(new Action(() => currentFileLabel.Text = e));
}

private void Animator_ProcessingSpeed(object sender, double e)
{
    // Update label or text box showing processing speed
    Invoke(new Action(() => processingSpeedLabel.Text = $"{e:F2} images/sec"));
}

but since it's creating a small file size 1.8MB  and only show frames of two three images from the list of 21 images i tried to change the method CreateAnimatedGifAsync
public async Task CreateAnimatedGifAsync(string outputFilePath, List<string> imagePaths, int frameDelay)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var collection = new MagickImageCollection())
        {
            int totalCount = imagePaths.Count;
            var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            for (int i = 0; i < totalCount; i++)
            {
                string imagePath = imagePaths[i];
                Console.WriteLine($"Processing {imagePath}"); // Basic logging
                CurrentFileProcessing?.Invoke(this, imagePath);

                using (var image = new MagickImage(imagePath))
                {
                    image.AnimationDelay = frameDelay; // Set frame delay
                    collection.Add(image);
                }

                int progressPercentage = (int)((i + 1) / (double)totalCount * 100);
                ProgressChanged?.Invoke(this, progressPercentage);

                double speed = (i + 1) / stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
                ProcessingSpeed?.Invoke(this, speed);
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Writing GIF to {outputFilePath}");
            collection.Write(outputFilePath);
            stopwatch.Stop();
        }
    });
}

but this changed version throwing now exception:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
and ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'MagickImage'.
and This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
ImageMagick.NativeInstance.Instance.get() in NativeInstance.cs
ImageMagick.MagickImage.NativeMagickImage.SetNext(System.IntPtr) in MagickImage.cs
ImageMagick.MagickImageCollection.DetachImages() in MagickImageCollection.cs
ImageMagick.MagickImageCollection.Write(string) in MagickImageCollection.cs
Download_Files.GifAnimator.CreateAnimatedGifAsync.AnonymousMethod__0() in GifAnimator.cs
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
